# Configure velocity tools with spring 3.x

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity

I am new to both spring and velocity 
I want to configure velocity tools with spring 3.x
but I could not find a good article on that
+ the velocity template is not showing the session variable
I set from Spring controller

Comment: Are there no appropriate answers here?

Answer (score 4):

As for configuring Velocity tools in spring 3.x, first put your tools.xml file somewhere useful, eg: /WEB-INF/vm/toolbox.xml
THEN configure your view resovler to look in that place:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    ...
    <!--Other config properties in here -->
    ...
    <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/vm/toolbox.xml" />
</bean>
```

An example toolbox.xml file:

```
<toolbox>
<xhtml>true</xhtml>
<tool>
    <key>date</key>
    <scope>application</scope>
    <class>org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.DateTool</class>
    <parameter name="format" value="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</tool>
<tool>
    <key>display</key>
    <scope>application</scope>
    <class>org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.DisplayTool</class>
</tool>
<tool>
    <key>math</key>
    <scope>application</scope>
    <class>org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.MathTool</class>
</tool>
<tool>
    <key>iter</key>
    <scope>application</scope>
    <class>org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.IteratorTool</class>
</tool>
<tool>
    <key>sort</key>
    <scope>application</scope>
    <class>org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.SortTool</class>
</tool>
</toolbox>
```

Hope this bit helps, at least.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have part of this working, but you haven't given much detail so I don't know how far you've got. So I'll give you a general answer: first learn the basics of Spring MVC and then use the Spring documentation to understand the Velocity integration. Once you have a working web application using Spring MVC with JSPs, it's a pretty small step to use Velocity templates instead of JSPs.

So first run through a good tutorial about Spring MVC, such as this one:
http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/

Then when you've got that working, read the (fairly short) Spring documentation about Velocity at:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-velocity

Essentially you'll need to use the `VelocityViewResolver` documented there instead of the `InternalResourceViewResolver` from the tutorial. Then create .vm Velocity templates in place of the .jsp files to display your pages.

Comment: thanks for your reply i have successfully integrated spring mvc and velocity but the template is not showing the session variable
suppose when i do this
ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("helloWorld");
view.addObject("message", "Hello World Session");
the tempate renders this correctly but when i do this
request.getSession().setAttribute("message1", "Hello World Session");
the template is not rendering the message1 correctly

Comment: Looks like spring is populating velocity context with Spring model data How can spring populate the velocity context with session and application scope data should i have to set velocity tools or any configuration changes?

Comment: I think that's exactly how the view is mean to work: it displays data from the Spring model... it's not meant to display data from other sources like session or application scope. If you want to display session (etc) data, then add it to the Spring model using `view.addObject()`.

Comment: Spring provides out dated support for velocity
i have a lot of data stored in my session 
and i cant to that ,
now i have decided to use freemarker 
that supports the session and application