# Error while loading Velocity template in Spring MVC(org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource)

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity

I am getting the 
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource error. can some one help me to figure out the issue.I have attached my code below.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

[I placed the .vm in the class path src folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c11eL.png)

```
Controller look like
```

`@RequestMapping("/velocity")
    public String velocity(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        final VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
        ve.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        ve.init();
        /* next, get the Template */
        final Template t = ve.getTemplate("index.vm");
        /* create a context and add data */
        final VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        context.put("members", "sharat");
        /* now render the template into a StringWriter */
        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(context, writer);
        final String Html = writer.toString();
        return Html;
    }`

spring-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/" />
</bean>

 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
</bean>
```

Error:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'index.vm'
org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:474)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:352)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1514)
org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.getTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:373)
```

velocity.properties

`resource.loader =  class
file.resource.loader.description = Velocity File Resource Loader
file.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
file.resource.loader.path = vm
file.resource.loader.cache = false
file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval = 0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
resource.loader =  class
```

with

```
resource.loader =  file
```

Also, if you're in a webapp, you should check the [WebappResourceLoader](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/view/WebappResourceLoader.html) from the [Velocity Tools](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/) subproject, which will help you specify a path relative to the root of the webapp. You can easily find online [how to configure Spring with Velocity Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470596/configure-velocity-tools-with-spring-3-x).

Otherwise, you will have to specify an absolute path for the `file.resource.loader.path` property, or be sure that the current execution path of your webapp container contains a `vm` directory with your templates within.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue.really appreciate your help.